# Extension to String in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

I create a class and adds an extension to it with the same signature as a member function and executes this method it always executes member method.

```
class Worker {
   fun work() = "...working"
}
fun Worker.work() = "...still working"
```

and I create an extension to String class for an already available method `replace` and executes this `replace` method; it invokes extension method instead and give **Hell** as output.

```
   fun String.replace(oldValue: String, newValue: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): String =  this.substring(0, this.length - 1);
```

then

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val worker = Worker()
    println(worker.work()) // output: ...working

    val myString= "Hello"
    val result1 = myString.replace("Hello", "Bye")
    println("First character is: $result1") // output: First character is: Hell
}
```

what is that I am missing? I was expecting replace would give **Bye** as output.

```
val myString= "Hello"
val result1 = myString.replace("Hello", "Bye")
println("First character is: $result1") // output: First character is: Bye
```

How String works in Kotlin with Extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the existing `replace` function in the standard library is also an extension function, declared in the `kotlin.text` package.

```
fun String.replace(oldChar: Char, newChar: Char, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): String
```

You are able to access it because `kotlin.text` is implicitly imported.

Because both your `replace` and the existing `replace` are extension functions, but the existing `replace` is implicitly imported, overload resolution chooses your `replace`.

The exact priorities are described in the [language specification](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#call-with-an-explicit-receiver):

> If a call is correct, for a callable f with an explicit receiver e of
> type T the following sets are analyzed (**in the given order**):
>
> 1. Non-extension member callables named f of type T;
> 2. [...]
> 3. [...]
> 4. Extension callables named f, whose receiver type U conforms to type T, declared in the package scope;
> 5. [...]
> 6. Implicitly imported extension callables named f (either from the Kotlin standard library or platform-specific ones), whose receiver
>    type U conforms to type T.
>
> [...]
>
> When analyzing these sets, the **first** set which contains **any** applicable callable is picked for c-level partition, which gives us the resulting overload candidate set.

Set 6 contains the existing `replace` in the standard library. Set 4 contains the `replace` and `work` extensions that you have declared. Set 1 contains the `work` method declared in `Worker`.

Because of this order in which Kotlin looks up a name, you see different results depending on where the original function is declared and how it is imported.

Comment: explanation is logically making sense to me but what would be the behaviour with third libraries and other Kotlin in-build libraries which are using this replace method since we are changing the functionality of it.

Comment: @TheVOYOU The "other libraries" would be in a different package than your code. They would need to import your package in order to have access to your package's extension functions. And if they do, then yes, you would be able to alter their behaviour by writing your own extension function (Explicitly imported extension functions go in Set 3 or 5 depending on how they are imported). But obviously they don't.

Comment: @TheVOYOU And you are not "changing" the functionality of anything. You are just declaring an extra function, and the Kotlin overload resolution happens to pick the one you declared when you wrote `replace` in `main`. What the overload resolution picks when other libraries say `replace`, is another matter. It probably won't be your `replace`, because the other libraries is not likely to import your package, and your `replace` will be in none of those sets.